# 401 error when trying to authenticate with reddit api and python 3

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, reddit

I'm trying to authenticate using a python 3 script **without** `PRAW` or any other wrapper. Both reddit's official documentation and what I've found searching refer to python 2's urllib utils. [This](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example) is the guide I'm using to write the code.

I've set up in my reddit profile an application configuration for a script application. Extracted from it both `app_password` and `app_id`. I'm also using my reddit account credentials, `user_id` and `user_psw`, in order to authenticate as displayed in the guide previously linked.

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request as request
import urllib.parse as parse

pman = request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pman.add_password(None, "https://reddit.com",
                                  app_id,
                                  app_password)
handler = request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pman)
opener = request.build_opener(handler)
request.install_opener(opener)

        # headers
        d = {"grant_type": "password",
             "username": user_id,
             "password": user_pass}
        post_data = parse.urlencode(d).encode("utf-8")

        headers = {"User-Agent": "QuickParsingScript/0.1 by user_id"}

response = request.Request("https://reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
                                   data=post_data, headers=headers)

request.urlopen(response) # urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

I've noticed that in python 2 urllib you can `POST` using a dictionary, but in p3's `Request` you have the following restriction:

> The supported object types include bytes, file-like objects, and iterables.

I'm using `urllib.parse.urlencode()` because I found a SO talking about moving http auth calls and general urllib operations from a p2 codebase to a p3 one. So it might be an encoding problem? I've also thought about the password manager using `"https://reddit.com"` as uri rendering my request invalid but I don't know how to check whether the root cause comes from there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Try "https://www.reddit.com" and "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token", respectively. I believe reddit returns 301 redirect for your request.`

Answered on [r/redditdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/6cwvtv/401_error_when_trying_to_authenticate_with_reddit/).